# Make powerline more reliable with less bandwidth

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

TL;DR: Is there a way to limit powerline bandwidth to increase link stability?

I got a powerline connection between two sockets with a 200Mbit connection (500MBit TPLink devices, it detects usually ~200Mbit between the sockets) and each adapter with two ethernet ports. The internal switch in the adapter only supports 100MBit, so even though the connection runs with 200MBit, i can only use 100. Thats fine, I knew this when I bought them. Problem is, sometimes while streaming games to my steam link or streaming something from my fileserver, the connection simply stops for 10s. It isn't the receivers or senders fault, it never happens in rooms with cable connection. But since I don't need the full 200Mbit, I thought about limiting it to 50, 75 or 100Mbit. Is there a way to limit the bandwidth to increase error correction and hopefully therefore link stability?

Thanks!

Edit: I will try to find out how to filter other electrical devices, but for the sake of the question, let's say that I cannot change my environment, only the powerline settings.

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to alleviate the symptoms in stead of tackling the real problem...

10 whole seconds? That sounds as if one of the Powerline adapters is rebooting and needs to re-establish connection. (10 seconds is just about the time for that.)

Are you sure you don't have an intermittent electrical problem (voltage spike or line-noise) that causes one of them to reboot  once in a while ?   Your computers/other devices may never notice such a thing because their power-supplies have a little more buffer capacity.

I had exactly the same thing happening when the electrical water-pump of my central heating system kicked in. (It didn't happen every time, but at least 4-5 times a day.)
One Powerline adapter (I've got the Gigabit version made by TP-link) closest to the heater would reboot. The other one would keep going.
I had to put a line-noise filter between the heating-system and the wall-outlet.
(You obviously can't do this on the Powerline adapter side as the noise-filter would also filter part of the Powerline signals.)
Just moving one of the adapters to another outlet, if possible, could already be enough to make the problem go away.

Comment: Thanks, I might try that with my fridge, since it is the only big electrical device running and it is happening far more often than with you (10 times per hour maybe.)

Comment: @JakobLenfers With that kind of frequency simply unplug the fridge for 15 minutes and see if it happens again during those 15. (15 minutes won't defrost the fridge if you keep the door closed.) If it happens during those 15 it isn't the fridge.

Comment: Good idea. Have some restrictions (small child) that make that hard to test quickly (and I already ordered a filter), but smart idea. :)